# MAX_BATCH_ROWS not working for external function in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created an external function like below with MAX_BATCH_ROWS (Its a latest snowflake version)

```
create or replace external function my_ext_function(columnValue varchar, schemeName varchar, current_user varchar, current_role varchar, current_available_roles varchar)
    returns variant
    MAX_BATCH_ROWS = 100000
    api_integration = [aws_api_integration]
    HEADERS = ('accept','application/json')
    CONTEXT_HEADERS = (current_user, current_role)
    as '[aws_api_post_url]'
```

Later I have created an internal function like below to access the external function

```
create or replace function my_ext_function_internal(columnValue varchar, schemaName varchar)
  returns variant
as $$ select my_ext_function(columnValue::string, schemaName, current_user, 'null', 'null') $$
```

Above works great except the MAX_BATCH_ROWS. The external function calls an api gateway in AWS which is tied to my lambda function. I have print statements in lambda to display rows coming from snowflake and its always somewhere between 1950 to 2050. Increasing or decreasing MAX_BATCH_ROWS does not makes any difference.

How can I make sure snowflake sends 100k rows in one go to my lambda function? How can i verify snowflake is sending rows prescribed in MAX_BATCH_ROWS. Highly appreciate any response.

Answer (score 2):

Batch sizes are not guaranteed:

> Because batch size and row order are not guaranteed, writing a function that returns a value for a row that depends upon any other row in this batch or previous batches can produce non-deterministic results.

> Note also that because batch size is not guaranteed, counting batches is not meaningful.

- https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/external-functions-general.html

`MAX_BATCH_ROWS` acts as a hint, but the actual size of each batch can't be controlled.

Comment: Thanks for your acknowledgement! By the way, Stack Overflow people love when you upvote and accept their answers (if they are useful to you).